# Carbylamine Reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, reactivity, reaction-control

In my lab manual, it is given that alcoholic KOH should be the base used in carbylamine test. However as it was not available, I used 10℅ NaOH. The test results came out positive. (Yes, it was actually a 1° amine) Is there any reason to prefer alcoholic KOH over NaOH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My memory tells me that KOH is more soluble in ethanol than NaOH. The chemistry is the same, just more efficient at the higher concentration.

Comment: What's the use of ethanol? The elimination at the last step?